# getData() doesn't work, returns empty in magento 2

Tags: magento2

The code snippet below returns empty collection:

```
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->load();
```

Comment: Will anyone suggest me a solution, please?

Comment: getData is not working on What ?

Comment: @AmitBera On the collection $categoryProducts itself!